# Following Istio TCP Traffic authorization tutorial and getting 'connection rejected' instead of 'connection succeeded'

Tags: security, kubernetes, authorization, istio

I'm following the Istio security authorization [TCP Traffic tutorial](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authorization/authz-tcp/).

On step 5, *Verify that sleep successfully communicates with tcp-echo on port 9002.*, I get a `connection rejected` result rather than the `connection succeeded` that the tutorial indicates I should receive.

```
user@docker-host-01:~/istio-1.20.1$ kubectl exec "$(kubectl get pod -l app=sleep -n foo -o jsonpath={.items..metadata.name})" \
>     -c sleep -n foo -- sh -c \
>     'echo "port 9000" | nc tcp-echo 9000' | grep "hello" && echo 'connection succeeded' || echo 'connection rejected'
hello port 9000
connection succeeded

user@docker-host-01:~/istio-1.20.1$ kubectl exec "$(kubectl get pod -l app=sleep -n foo -o jsonpath={.items..metadata.name})" \
>     -c sleep -n foo -- sh -c \
>     'echo "port 9001" | nc tcp-echo 9001' | grep "hello" && echo 'connection succeeded' || echo 'connection rejected'
hello port 9001
connection succeeded

user@docker-host-01:~/istio-1.20.1$ TCP_ECHO_IP=$(kubectl get pod "$(kubectl get pod -l app=tcp-echo -n foo -o jsonpath={.items..metadata.name})" -n foo -o jsonpath="{.status.podIP}")
user@docker-host-01:~/istio-1.20.1$ kubectl exec "$(kubectl get pod -l app=sleep -n foo -o jsonpath={.items..metadata.name})" \
>     -c sleep -n foo -- sh -c \
>     "echo \"port 9002\" | nc $TCP_ECHO_IP 9002" | grep "hello" && echo 'connection succeeded' || echo 'connection rejected'
connection rejected

user@docker-host-01:~/istio-1.20.1$ echo $TCP_ECHO_IP
10.244.0.27

user@docker-host-01:~/istio-1.20.1$ kubectl exec "$(kubectl get pod -l app=sleep -n foo -o jsonpath={.items..metadata.name})"     -c sleep -n foo -- sh -c     "echo \"port 9002\" | nc $TCP_ECHO_IP 9002"

user@docker-host-01:~/istio-1.20.1$
```

The logs below appear to indicate that the message is being sent from the `sleep` pod, but never being received by the `tcp-echo` pod. If I understand correctly, the log entry that the connection to `10.244.0.27:9002` was routed to the `PassthroughCluster` indicates that it's not properly routing by IP, where it routes correctly by pod name in the previously to entries.

```
user@docker-host-01:~/istio-1.20.1$ kubectl logs -l app=sleep -c istio-proxy -n foo
[2024-01-01T14:59:50.262Z] "- - -" 0 - - - "-" 10 16 9 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "10.244.0.27:9000" outbound|9000||tcp-echo.foo.svc.cluster.local 10.244.0.26:52798 10.111.194.106:9000 10.244.0.26:36087 - -
[2024-01-01T14:59:54.343Z] "- - -" 0 - - - "-" 10 16 9 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "10.244.0.27:9001" outbound|9001||tcp-echo.foo.svc.cluster.local 10.244.0.26:43342 10.111.194.106:9001 10.244.0.26:42365 - -
[2024-01-01T15:00:02.734Z] "- - -" 0 - - - "-" 10 0 0 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "10.244.0.27:9002" PassthroughCluster 10.244.0.26:33738 10.244.0.27:9002 10.244.0.26:33999 - -
2024-01-01T15:02:03.306941Z     info    xdsproxy        connected to upstream XDS server: istiod.istio-system.svc:15012
[2024-01-01T15:03:52.319Z] "- - -" 0 - - - "-" 10 0 0 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "10.244.0.27:9002" PassthroughCluster 10.244.0.26:34762 10.244.0.27:9002 10.244.0.26:44177 - -

user@docker-host-01:~/istio-1.20.1$ kubectl logs -l app=tcp-echo -c istio-proxy -n foo
[2024-01-01T14:59:50.263Z] "- - -" 0 - - - "-" 554 590 8 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "10.244.0.27:9000" inbound|9000|| 127.0.0.6:58755 10.244.0.27:9000 10.244.0.26:52798 outbound_.9000_._.tcp-echo.foo.svc.cluster.local -
[2024-01-01T14:59:54.344Z] "- - -" 0 - - - "-" 554 590 8 - "-" "-" "-" "-" "10.244.0.27:9001" inbound|9001|| 127.0.0.6:43015 10.244.0.27:9001 10.244.0.26:43342 outbound_.9001_._.tcp-echo.foo.svc.cluster.local -
```

I would appreciate help understanding why my environment is causing the tutorial commands to deviate from the expected output and how to correct it. Thank you!

Environment details:

- minikube v1.32.0 on Ubuntu 20.04
- Kubernetes v1.28.3 on Docker 24.0.7
- bridge CNI
- istio v1.20.1